# Investing in mining still worth it?

Tags: ether, proof-of-stake

I recently read that Ethereum will be switching from PoW to PoS soon, will this kill GPU mining? I'm asking since I'm looking to build myself a miner as both a summer project and a way to make some money, but is it still worth it at this point to invest in a mining setup?

Thank you in advance.
Joey

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  Please check https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask